# one Httacees RewriteCond for all Rules

Tags: .htaccess

I want to write one Httacees RewriteCond for all RewriteRules

that is possible

I want do not repeat the RewriteCond  for every rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?sub_domain=%1  [L,QSA]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^login$ /login.php?sub_domain=%1  [L,QSA]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^signup$ /signup.php?sub_domain=%1  [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Is your htaccess common for multiple domains?

Comment: @anubhava one domain , just want not repeat write condition for every rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check condition only once and set an environment variable with capture group `%1` and then use env variable in your rules like this:

```bash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.[NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=DN:%1]

# rewrite login or signup
RewriteRule ^(login|signup)/?$ $1.php?sub_domain=%{ENV:DN} [L,QSA,NC]

# rewrite landing page
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?sub_domain=%{ENV:DN} [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: what about if the pages have diffrent parameters like  RewriteRule ^reset/([^/]*)$ /reset.php?sub_domain=%1&code=$1  [L,QSA]

Comment: That will become `RewriteRule ^reset/([^/]*)$ reset.php?sub_domain=%{ENV:DN}&code=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: anubhava,thanks , very nice anwser from you